# Overriding Default Tablesorter Settings

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I have an application with a central controller that triggers `tablesorter()` for every `.tablesorter` class.

On certain pages, I'd like to override the default tablesorter settings, for example:

```
$('#item-list').tablesorter({ headers: { 0: { sorter: false } } });
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, and the default settings are kept. Is there an easy method to do this?

Alternatively, I tried to use `trigger` to make changes on the fly, but wasn't able to make it work with the `header` property, or find any documentation for how to modify it dynamically.

Comment: The jQuery selector is targeting an ID. Target the tables using a common class name.

Comment: I'm doing precisely that: .tablesorter is the common class selector. However, I would like to override it with a specific ID on some pages. The question is how this is done.